Blender doesn't render color, why?

what could have happened? It's colorless, I need the color to create poses


It was meant to be like this, it stays that color on its own, no need to add texture

It doesn't have the shading tab


Could you show the Material Properties panel ? You can also share your blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/.

It's not clear what you are asking, the material of your object is white, so it appears white. Note that you have deactivated the lights for the viewport, so the rend will look different.

plus i'm not sure what's the relation you do between the color and the pose?

There is no texture connected to shader's color input, so it displays a single color *which is set to white.
There is no bug here, just someone has wrongly set the material.
• Now the material is:

• It should be changed to:


where do i find this part to edit the color?

There's a Shading tab on the top toolbar to show that view, but see this video for a quick introduction to shading in Blender. From some of your questions here I'd strongly recommend following a beginners course on using Blender! There are lots available on YT.

@JohnEason - The attached .blend file uses HIGHLY modified Blender environment, which does NOT have Shading tab nor any other usual options aside from ones which are used in animating process. I assume the author of initial post having zero experience with Blender *and just was provided with this file by some other person (e.g. by an employer or a client).  Hence I see as the only proper option to answer in a way which would be helpful to a person who is experienced enough to set such environment  (in case if the answer will be redirected to a person who's provided the file)

@JohnEason - And, by the way, leaving comments for the initial poster under the other's posts is not effective *since the initial poster will not be notified about such comments and highly likely will miss them. Hence - next time you want to address comments to the initial poster - I recommend you either answer under the initial question or tag the person (like I tagged you in the beginning of this message)

@Yaroslav Looking closely at that screenshot, I suspect that may be the UPBGE version of Blender rather than the standard one, hence the lack of the Shading tab. The reason I commented here is because I was commenting to the original poster's comment which was a comment to your answer. In fact, if you try adding a comment here with two 'nicknames' in the comment you get a warning which specifically says that the original poster would be notified anyway!

@JohnEason I think that warning means the original poster of the answer, not the original poster of the question. You would need to @ bnana for them to get a notification here
